# Overriding method in TestInitialize of Ms Unit Test Framework not working

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a child class that implements my base class and the base class has a [TestClass] decorator. I want to call a Setup method in the child class from the base class but while debugging, execution does not make it to the child class and I'm not sure why. This is what I have:

```
[TestClass]
public class BaseTestClass
{

  [TestInitialize]
  public virtual void Setup() { }
 }
```

Then in the child class I have this:

```
 public class Child : BaseTestClass
 {
      public override void Setup()
      {
       // A lot of setup code
      }

 }
```

The overrided Setup() method is never invoked. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Don't put the attributes on the base class, only the actual test classes.

Comment: Mark the overriding method with the attribute and retry.

Comment: seems odd whatever you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

@KeithNicholas You're reply made me think about what I was doing and I think I was going about this in the wrong way.  I changed it to be like this:

```
 [TestClass]
 public class Child : Base
 {

 // All tests go here
 [TestMethod]
 public void TestSomething()
 { }



 public class Base
 {
   // declare variables

  [TestInitialize]
  public void Setup()
  {
    // Create test records
  }

  [TestCleanup]
  public void Teardown()
  {
    // Delete test records
  }
```

I don't know which way is better, but I was never able to get execution to step into the overrided Setup() method even when only putting the [TestInitialize] decorator on the that method only.